# ROS Approximate Time sync not entering callback

Tags: c++, ros

I am trying to subscribe to a pointcloud and it's normal from to different subscribers and pass it on to a common function via approximate time sync. Please find minimal code below:

```
void OrganizedMultiPlaneSegmentation::onInit() {
sub = private_nh.subscribe("/cloud/cloud_out_merged",1,&OrganizedMultiPlaneSegmentation::segment,this,ros::TransportHints().tcpNoDelay()); 
} 

void OrganizedMultiPlaneSegmentation::segment(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& msg){
  ros::NodeHandle& nh_ = getNodeHandle();

  sub1_.subscribe(nh_, "/cloud/cloud_out_merged",5);
   if (sub1_.getSubscriber().getNumPublishers() == 1)
    {
          // NODELET_INFO("Got a subscriber to scan, starting subscriber to merged pointcloud");
    }
  sub2_.subscribe(nh_, "/cloud_out_normal",5);
     if (sub2_.getSubscriber().getNumPublishers() == 1)
    {
          // NODELET_INFO("Got a subscriber to scan, starting subscriber to normal pointcloud");
    }
  typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2,sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> MySyncPolicy;
  Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(40), sub1_, sub2_);
//   sync.setAgePenalty(1.0);
  sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&OrganizedMultiPlaneSegmentation::segmentPlanes,this, _1, _2));
}

// Callback function to be called
    void OrganizedMultiPlaneSegmentation::segmentPlanes(const PointCloud2ConstPtr &cloud_msg1,const PointCloud2ConstPtr &cloud_msg2)
    {
    pcl::PointCloud<pointT>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pointT>());
    pcl::fromROSMsg(*cloud_msg1,*cloud);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normalCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>());
```

I have tried changing queue size of the subscriber, the buffer size of the policy, and both don't seem to work. Please let me know if there is something obvious that I am doing wrong,or what can be possible causes and remedies for this. Happy to provide more information and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to play with [slop](https://answers.ros.org/question/364729/what-is-slop-in-approximatetimesynchronizer/) parameter of `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer`. It is responsible for how big can be the difference between timestamps of the messages to consider them synchronized.

Also one the basic checks is to verify that messages on the topic `/cloud/cloud_out_merged` and `/cloud_out_normal` are being published at all :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Will checkout slop or the c++ equivalent of it.
The way the callback is being called seems to be correct right?

Yup, I have made sure they are being published, here is terminal output
`seven-robot-2@seven-robot-2:~$ rostopic hz /cloud_out_normal
subscribed to [/cloud_out_normal]
average rate: 6.806
 min: 0.142s max: 0.150s std dev: 0.00280s window: 7
average rate: 6.769
 min: 0.142s max: 0.155s std dev: 0.00403s window: 13
average rate: 6.746`

Comment: `seven-robot-2@seven-robot-2:~$ rostopic hz /cloud/cloud_out_merged
subscribed to [/cloud/cloud_out_merged]
average rate: 6.583
 min: 0.132s max: 0.180s std dev: 0.01589s window: 6
average rate: 6.434
 min: 0.132s max: 0.180s std dev: 0.01507s window: 13
average rate: 6.435
 min: 0.132s max: 0.180s std dev: 0.01407s window: 19
average rate: 6.393
 min: 0.132s max: 0.180s std dev: 0.01241s window: 25`

Comment: Hmm, looks like c++ version doesn't have that exact parameter. But I think you may consider using [inter message lower bound](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/message_filters/html/c++/structmessage__filters_1_1sync__policies_1_1ApproximateTime.html#a02b528be0573c932f8b6aab2af0df619) instead

Comment: I tried using setMaxIntervalDuration instead, but no luck. Will try this